# macbook rEFIt dual boot mbr issue

Tags: macos, ubuntu, macbook, mbr, refit

I have ubuntu and osx installed on my macbook.  It was working fine up until recently.  Now, when I boot I have a 20 second period where it makes the mac boot noise and then proceeds to show a grey screen.  After 20 seconds it shows the rEFIt boot loader with my options.  I have tried reinstalling rEFIt and going through that installation.  It continues to show the same screen.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Are there any external hard drives plugged in and turned on during boot up? That tends to slow down my rEFIt loading quite a bit, which manifests as a blank grey screen as well.

Comment: Wow sorry, just saw this response.  No there were no drives plugged in during boot.  I now am experiencing issues with booting in general.  When I have the battery plugged in it refuses to boot.  I have to take the battery out and boot via power plug.  May replace the battery to try that as a resolution.